Is there a tool to decompose 4-Qubit unitaries (aka 16x16 matrices)?
I was wondering if there is a tool that can decompose such a matrix in gates on 4 qubits?
I found one for 3-qubit gates (9x9 matrices) in Cirq but nothing for bigger matrices.
(The matrix is not trivial like a tensor product of two SWAP-Gates).

Qiskit supports the decomposition of any $2^n \times 2^n$ unitary matrax where $n$ the number of qubits using Quantum Shannon Decomposition method.
For example
from qiskit.synthesis import qs_decomposition
from scipy.stats import unitary_group
import numpy as np

# Construct a random unitary:
num_qubits = 4
unitary = unitary_group.rvs(2 ** num_qubits)

# Decompose it:
circ = qs_decomposition(unitary)
circ.draw('mpl')

Another option provided by Qiskit is the Approximate Quantum Compiler which constructs approximate circuit for your unitary that most of the time has smaller depth and uses smaller number of two-qubit gates.
from qiskit.synthesis.unitary.aqc import (
    AQC,
    CNOTUnitCircuit,
    FastCNOTUnitObjective,
    make_cnot_network,
)
from functools import partial
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Generate a network made of CNOT units
cnots = make_cnot_network(num_qubits=num_qubits)

# Create an optimizer to be used by AQC
optimizer = partial(minimize, method="L-BFGS-B")

# Create an instance
aqc = AQC(optimizer)

# Create a template circuit that will approximate our target circuit
approx_circ = CNOTUnitCircuit(num_qubits=num_qubits, cnots=cnots)

# Create an objective that defines our optimization problem
approximating_objective = FastCNOTUnitObjective(num_qubits=num_qubits, cnots=cnots)

# Run optimization process to compile the unitary
aqc.compile_unitary(
    target_matrix=unitary,
    approximate_circuit=approx_circ,
    approximating_objective=approximating_objective
)
approx_circ.draw('mpl')

